# Display card list horizontally, HTML/CSS with Angular and MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, materialize

I want to display a list of custom cards using `ng-repeat` directive, but it keeps displaying vertically.

```
    <style>
    li{
        display: inline
    }
    </style>
<div ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <ul >
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m2 20 " >
          <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
              <span class="card-title" id="dani">{{x}}</span>
              <p id="p">I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
              I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
              <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
display: inline-flex;
```

fixes the problem, but puts the objects one after another on the same row. I want to go to a next row after lets say, 4 objects, so how can i set this up?

Update 2:
here's what i want to achieve:
[image]

so after 3 card displayed horizontally the line to increase :)

Comment: try adding a `display: inline-flex;` to your `ul` element.

Answer (score 0):

for li tag use floating to left

```
li {
 float: left;
}
```

additionaly for ul add list-style-type:none;

Comment: unfortunately, this does not fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your repeat is on the line item.  You are literally telling it that you want it vertically.  Move your repeat to the span tag,  you may also need to add display of inline-block and set a width on your span.  Try this:

```
    <div ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <ul >
    <li>
    <div ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
  <ul >
    <li>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m2 20 " >
          <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
              <span style="display:inline-block; width:100px" ng-repeat="x in names" class="card-title" id="dani">{{x}}<br>
              <span style="display:inline-block" id="p">I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
              I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</span></span>

            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
              <a href="#">This is a link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6DIGzHfG1X4xEUCD5Rtk?p=preview). Let me know if this is not what you were trying to do.

Comment: It looks like the cards are put one in top of another, so this solution does not work, unfortunately :( .

Comment: I wasn't sure where the "p" paragraph was supposed to go so I put it under the names.  Your question was not 100% clear, but you should be able to use the example to get what you need.  If not, you might want to show a pic of exactly what you want, even if it is hardcoded.  I'm trying to help you, but I'm not really sure what exactly you need.  I gave you two examples in the Plunker because I thought they would help.